# How can I replace multiple try/except blocks with less code?

Tags: python

I find myself writing code as below quite a bit.  It's very verbose.  What I'd like to do is assign array indeces to different variables, and if there's an indexerror, assign false.  I feel like there should be a shorter syntax for doing this (compared to what I have below).

Edit - here's my actual code.  `page` is a valid lxml.html object.  Each of the selectors may or may not return a value, depending on whether that section is present on the page.

```
def extract_data( page ):
    # given lxml.html obj, extract data from g+ page and return as dict
    try:
        profile_name = page.xpath( '//div[@guidedhelpid="profile_name"]/text()' )[0]
    except IndexError:
        profile_name = False
    try:
        website = page.cssselect( 'span.K9a' )[0].text_content().rstrip('/')
    except IndexError:
        website = False

    try:
        contact_div = html.tostring( page.xpath( '//div[normalize-space(text())="Contact Information"]/../../..' )[0] )
    except IndexError:
        contact_div = False

    return {
        'profile_name'      :   profile_name,
        'website'           :   website,
        'contact_div'       :   contact_div,
    }
```

Comment: Unrelated suggestions: `list( 1,2 )` should be `[1, 2]` and no variable should be named `l` (if you really want a single-letter L, use `L` instead). See http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/

Comment: About your actual question: What are you trying to do? Since it's about lxml maybe there's a cleaner way to do what you're trying to do...

Comment: @travis-leleu, do you really need access to all items of the list at one time? Generally you process items from the list one at a time in which case the code would be `for item in L: do_something(item)`

Comment: @ThiefMaster updated the question with my actual code.  How would you replace all those try/except blocks?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming what you're trying to do makes sense within the context of your use case, you can encapsulate this notion of a default value inside a function:

```
def retrieve(my_list, index, default_value=False):
    try:
        return my_list[index]
    except IndexError:
        return default_value
```

That way you can do something like:

```
my_list = [2, 4]
first = retrieve(my_list, 0)
# first will be 2
second = retrieve(my_list, 1)
# second will be 4
third = retrieve(my_list, 2)
# third will be False
```

You can even change the value you'd like to default to in case the index does not exist.

In general, when you're repeating code like in the manner you're doing above, the first thing you should think about is whether you can write a function that does what you're trying to do.

---

Using your actual code, you could do something like:

```
profile_name = retrieve(page.xpath( '//div[@guidedhelpid="profile_name"]/text()'), 0)
website = retrieve(page.cssselect( 'span.K9a' ), 0)
if website:
    website = website.text_content().rstrip('/')
contact_div = retrieve(page.xpath( '//div[normalize-space(text())="Contact Information"]/../../..' ), 0)
if contact_div:
    contact_div = html.tostring(contact_div)
```

Comment: I'd make the default `None` instead of `False`. And you could always return *two* values, with the second one indicating whether the value is valid.

Comment: Yeah, I agree with you that `False` is a poor default value, but I won't presume to know what the OP's use case is outside of what's stated in the problem.

Comment: I updated the q with my actual code, maybe it'll make more sense now.  Why would I use None instead of False?

Comment: If you're interested in whether an object exists, `None` more properly enforces that notion. If you're interested in the truth-value of an expression, then `True/False` more closely maps to that concept.

Comment: @HuuNguyen gotcha, understood.  The final resting location of the data is in MongoDB, which I believe treats None and False the same.

Answer (score 1):

```
vars = ['first', 'second', 'third']
r = {}
for i, var in enumerate(vars):
    try:
        r[var] = l[i]
    except IndexError:
        r[var] = False
```

Answer (score 0):

This should solve your problem :) exec + looping to the rescue!

```
l = list([0,2])

numberWords = { 0:"first", 1:"second", 2:"third"}

for i in range(0,len(l)):
    try:
        exec(numberWords[i]+"=l["+str(i)+"]")
    except IndexError:
        exec(numberWords[i]+"=false")
```